# (Hint request) $n^{1/n^{1/3}}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I can show that $n^{1/n}$ converges to $1$ by using binomial theorem to deduce that $n^{1/n}-1$ converges to $0$. However, similar method does not, at least directly, apply to show that $n^{1/{n^{1/3}}}$ converges to $1$, which I am willing to believe to be true. Now, it would suffice to show that $n^{1/n^{1/3}}$ converges since then a subsequence of $n^{1/n^{1/3}}$ of cubes $n=k^3$ converges since $n^{1/n}$ converges. In the end, could someone give me a hint on how I can show that $n^{1/n^{1/3}}$ converges? It would be equivalently good to know if there is a hint on how to show that $n^{1/n^{1/3}}\rightarrow 1$ directly without using subsequences.

P.S. I am looking for a way that does not rely on results of differentiation other than basic differentiation rules regarding polynomials and basic functions.

Comment: You can take the log and try to show that $$\frac{\log n}{n^{1/3}} \to 0$$ this is easily proved using L'Hopital

Comment: @Crostul: Ooh, just beat me to it! :-) ETA: And you too, KaviRamaMurthy.

Comment: Have you tried root test

Comment: @Crostul I am looking for a way that does not useL’Hopital’s rule, and to work within the domain of basic properties of sequences.

Comment: @Nugi Since $\log x<x$ for $x>0$, we have $$
\frac{{\log n}}{{n^{1/3} }} = \frac{{4\log n^{1/4} }}{{n^{1/3} }} \le  \frac{{4n^{1/4} }}{{n^{1/3} }} = 4n^{ - 1/12}  \to 0.
$$

Comment: @nozalp10 For root test, the sequence converges if $\limsup n^{1/n^{4/3}}<1$. However, how can I show this? This seems as hard for me as the original sequence, and actually, I think this value is 1.

Comment: Since we can show $x<e^x$ using geometric series, this actually proves the convergence from elementary result. I Iike this answer!

Comment: @Nugi I don't see how the geometric series helps, but it follows obviously from the power series of $e^x$ or by noting that $$
e^x  = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left( {1 + \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n  \ge \lim_{n\to \infty} \left( {1 + n\frac{x}{n}} \right) = 1 + x > x
$$ if $x>0$.

Comment: Great, that is a clear reasoning for me. (I actually was thinking about power series of it and said geometric series.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put $x=\sqrt[3]n$. Then we get
$$n^{1/n^{1/3}}=(x^3)^{1/x}=(x^{1/x})^3$$
which converges to $1$ because $x^{1/x}$ converges to $1$.